# Не работает подсчёт процента

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу разобраться как сделать так чтобы отнимало 10% от всей суммы ввёденной заранее.
Представим есть кросовки = 1000, рюкзак = 2000, куртка = 1000, нужно сложить эти суммы и отнять от них процент. Я пытался но у меня или выходить неверно или отображает именно этот процент.

```
i = (backpack + krossovki + kurtka)
skidka = (i/10)
print(i+skidka)
```

Comment: Чтобы отнять нужно использовать знак минус. А вы скидку к цене прибавляете. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так подходит?

```py
i = (backpuck + krossovki + kurtka)

skidka = (i - i/10)
print(skidka)
```

Answer (score 0):

Так ты ж ничего и не отнимаешь, подсчитал скидку (вышло 400 по примеру) и к сумме 4000 добавляешь 400, как оно должно отниматься?
Задание не понял до конца, поэтому 2 варианта
1:

```
i = (backpack+krossovki+kurtka)
skidka = i-(i/10)
print(i+skidka) #i - 4000, skidka - 4000-400 = 3600, i+skidka = 7600
```

2:

```
i = (backpack+krossovki+kurtka)
skidka = i/10
print(i-skidka)#(i - 4000, скидка - 400, результат 3600)
```